# Change AngularJS ngTrim Behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angularjs-directive, textarea

I am using AngularJS version 1.5.6. I have a large application with lots of text areas and text inputs. I discovered a bug today caused by the default AngularJS behavior of trimming input for text type inputs. I would like to change this behavior from trimming by default to not trimming by default.

Is there an easy way to do this rather than to go through hundreds of textareas and text inputs in my application. (perhaps globally or writing my own directive?)

Here is the documentation page describing the default behavior of ng-trim (ngTrim).

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Comment: as per docs set `ng-trim="false"`

Comment: This might be a good use case for using JQuery to grab references to all of your textboxes and then set ng-trim to false. I don't normally advocate mixing Jquery code in with angular apps, but it seems like a pretty straight forward thing to do.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I see that, but I don't want to do that for hundreds of different elements.

Comment: @MikeFeltman I think that may be my best choice since my project has a JQuery dependency. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below directive should work for all the input type=text fields. It will set the value of ngTrim false by default for every input field. And a similar one can be created for the textarea if required.

```
.directive('input', function($compile){
   return {
   link(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (element.attr('type') === 'text') {
      attrs.$set('ngTrim', 'false');
    }
  }
  };
 });
```

Comment: @SKPall where would you specify it?

Comment: It can be added in the same module where controller has been added or in a new module.

Comment: Sorry. I get how to tie it into a module. Specifically where would you call the input directive, or are you implying that once this is loaded, it would be global and effect all inputs automatically?

Comment: As the directive name is 'input' itself, it will work for every 'input' element. So for all: <input type....>,  this will be called automatically.

Comment: @SKSpall so I made one for textarea, and I can see where angular adds the attribute to the text area element, but for some reason it isn't preventing the trimming from happening. Any ideas?

Comment: @SKSpall nevermind, I'm a dummy. I had attrs.$set('ngTrim',false). Missing the '' around false. Thanks!

Comment: Warning: some browsers won't support the way the link function is written. better to write as link:function(scope,element,attrs){} if older browsers need to be supported.