# Angularjs textarea input empty space not allowed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which has `textarea` control for description but can't insert empty space. Alphanumeric and numeric characters can be inserted but space character not allowed.

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" maxlength="{{vm.model.maxLength}}" 
id="comment" ng-model="vm.model.FreeText" ng-required="true" ng-maxlength="
{{vm.model.maxLength}}" ng-disabled="vm.model.FreeTextIsdisabled" ng-
trim="false"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ng-trim="false"` in your text area  because of  **If set to false `AngularJS` will not automatically trim the input.**

check this  as well : [Change AngularJS ngTrim Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309473/change-angularjs-ngtrim-behavior)

Comment: I have removed ng-trim="false" but stil can't use empty space. Thank you for interest